# Why does the Skype incoming call window disappear in Awesome WM?

Tags: awesome, skype

Skype used to work OK on Awesome WM for some months, but recently incoming call windows do not show up at all. I've checked all the tabs and tried to minimise all the other windows, and there is no status bar entry, so it looks like it's not floated behind any of them.

Removing the Awesome WM configuration file and restarting doesn't work.

Comment: This affects me as well. I always have to tell people that I call them back. Same for you?